# Public_activity deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have public_activity working on my rails app for the guidelines model.  But there is a problem with deleting a guideline.  Updating and creating guidelines are fine.

The error says

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (You cannot call create unless the parent is saved):
  app/controllers/guidelines_controller.rb:228:in `destroy'
```

guidelines_controller.rb

```
def destroy
    @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id])
    @guideline.destroy
   @guideline.create_activity :destroy, owner: current_user


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to guidelines_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

def update

    @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id])
    if @guideline.update_attributes(params[:guideline])
     @guideline.create_activity :update, owner: current_user
    end

def create
    @guideline = current_user.guidelines.new(params[:guideline])
    if @guideline.save
      @guideline.create_activity :create, owner: current_user
    end
```

guideline.rb

```
include PublicActivity::Common
```

view public_activity/guideline/_destroy.html.erb

```
deleted a guideline 
<% if activity.trackable %>
    <%= link_to activity.trackable.title, activity.trackable %>
<% else %>
    which can no longer be viewed
<% end %>
```

the rails log says

```
Processing by GuidelinesController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"SpdYUFk0Bv1KuVg6oEuDUU4MI3eD6C1nV/3bmd5Xhsg=", "id"=>"9-jannit"}
  Guideline Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "guidelines".* FROM "guidelines" WHERE "guidelines"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "9-jannit"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."guideline_id" = 9
  SQL (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM "guidelines" WHERE "guidelines"."id" = ?  [["id", 9]]
  SOLR Request (224.9ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x007f9ebdc5ea50> parameters={data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><delete><id>Guideline 9</id></delete>, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: } ]
   (3.3ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SOLR Request (4.8ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x007f9ebdc5ea50> parameters={data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><delete><id>Guideline 9</id></delete>, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: } ]
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 254ms
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a workaround on this?  I ended up getting it to work by moving `@guideline.create_activity :destroy, owner: current_user` before the `@guideline.destroy`.  I am not a fan of this in case the destroy does not actually go through.

Comment: I'm also having this problem, did you manage to fix it? Like @jameswilliamiii I'm not a fan of calling create_activity before the transaction

Comment: It's curious that here seems to work: http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity?autoplay=true

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try setting `:autosave => true` in your association. For instance:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  # or wherever location the guidelines association is being set
  has_many :guidelines, :autosave => true
 ...
end
```

Comment: thanks - I can add it to users.rb has_many :guidelines, :autosave => true but that doesn't make any difference

Comment: sorry, just to go back to your previous suggestion.  It does actually stop this error message coming up, but the 'deleting a guidelines' is not added to my trackable activities feed